# Ruby: How do we identify whether an object o has a class C as its ancestor in the class hierarchy?

Tags: ruby, class-hierarchy

In Ruby, is it possible to identify whether an object o has a class C as its ancestor in the class hierarchy using any method?

I've given an example below where I use a hypothetical method `has_super_class?` to accomplish it. How should I do this in reality?

```
o = Array.new
o[0] = 0.5
o[1] = 1
o[2] = "This is good"
o[3] = Hash.new

o.each do |value|
  if (value.has_super_class? Numeric)
    puts "Number"
  elsif (value.has_super_class? String)
    puts "String"
  else
    puts "Useless"
  end
end
```

Expected Output:

```
Number
Number
String
Useless
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `obj.kind_of?(Klassname)`:

```
1.kind_of?(Fixnum) => true
1.kind_of?(Numeric) => true
....
1.kind_of?(Kernel) => true
```

The `kind_of?` method has also an identical alternative `is_a?`.

If you want to check only whether an object is (direct) instance of a class, use `obj.instance_of?`:

```
1.instance_of?(Fixnum) => true
1.instance_of?(Numeric) => false
....
1.instance_of?(Kernel) => false
```

You can also list all ancestors of an object by calling the `ancestors` method on its `class`. For instance `1.class.ancestors` gives you `[Fixnum, Integer, Precision, Numeric, Comparable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.is_a?`

```
o = [0.5, 1, "This is good", {}]

o.each do |value|
  if (value.is_a? Numeric)
    puts "Number"
  elsif (value.is_a? String)
    puts "String"
  else
    puts "Useless"
  end
end

# =>
Number
Number
String
Useless
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o.class.ancestors
```

using that list, we can implement has_super_class? like this (as singletone method):

```
def o.has_super_class?(sc)
  self.class.ancestors.include? sc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The rad way:

```
1.class.ancestors => [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
1.class <= Fixnum => true
1.class <= Numeric => true
1.class >= Numeric => false
1.class <= Array => nil
```

If you want to be fancy with it, you could do something like this:

```
is_a = Proc.new do |obj, ancestor|
  a = { 
    -1 => "#{ancestor.name} is an ancestor of #{obj}",
    0 => "#{obj} is a #{ancestor.name}",
    nil => "#{obj} is not a #{ancestor.name}",
  }
  a[obj.class<=>ancestor]
end

is_a.call(1, Numeric) => "Numeric is an ancestor of 1"
is_a.call(1, Array) => "1 is not a Array"
is_a.call(1, Fixnum) => "1 is a Fixnum"
```